# Scrollbar gets hide when splitter pane is moved upward

Tags: css, telerik, blazor

when i move the splitter pane upwards scrollbar which is present on the page gets hide and again when splitter pane is moved downward the scrollbar is visible.I tried using max,min height,position fixed but still the scrollbar is getting hide.Is there any way how to stop hiding the scrollbar when splitter pane is moved upward`

```html
 <TelerikSplitter OnResize="@OnResize"
                         Orientation="@SplitterOrientation.Vertical">
            <SplitterPanes>
                <AuthorizeView Roles="SuperAdmin">                    
                        <SplitterPane Collapsible="true" Resizable="true" Collapsed="false">
                            <CompanyList @ref="@cmpCompanyList" OnCompanySelectionChanged="async ()=>await  RefreshUserList()">
                            </CompanyList>
                        </SplitterPane>                
                </AuthorizeView>
                <AuthorizeView Roles="SuperAdmin,UserAdmin">
                    <SplitterPane Resizable="true" Collapsible="true">
                        <CascadingValue Value="@selectedcompany">
                            <UserList @ref="@cmpUsers">

                            </UserList>
                        </CascadingValue>

                    </SplitterPane>
                </AuthorizeView>

            </SplitterPanes>
        </TelerikSplitter>
```

`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which scrollbar disappears? On which pane? What are the CSS overflow settings on your content? Does setting height to 100% and overflow to auto in your content help? If not, as a few bits of html that mimic your layout instead of custom components in the panes.